# Tracking mouse move events outside the Native-Client plug-in's area

Tags: google-chrome, google-nativeclient

In a Google's Native-Client plug-in, is there a way, upon a mouse-down event, to start to capture all mouse-move events, until the mouse-up event fires, even when the mouse cursor is moved outside the plug-in area?

I have a 3D application that allows the user to manipulate 3D objects, (drag/rotate etc) and upon a mouse-down event occurring within the plug-in area, the user is free to manipulate the object and move the mouse even outside of the plug-in area to complete his manipulation. The manipulation is designed to really stops only upon the mouse-up event, even though the mouse has been moved outside the plug-in's area.

The only thing I found until now that is close to the required behavior, is using the pp::MouseLock class, and lock the mouse upon a mouse-down, and unlocking it upon a mouse-up. The cursor is hidden during the lock, but I do receive the mouse-move and mouse-up events even when the mouse is moved outside the plug-in area. But this is clearly not the ideal solution, since (1) the mouse cursor is hidden during the user's interaction, (2) the mouse is automatically unlocked by the browser as soon as the plug-in looses focus, and (3) upon the mouse-up event, the mouse cursor is restored to the location where the mouse-down event happened, instead of preserving its current final position (outside the plug-in's area).

So I need something better, that will allow me to track the mouse position during manipulation, even outside my plug-in area.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this without MouseLock? AFAICT, the plugin already has this behavior; i.e. you will continue to get mouse move events outside of the plugin area after you click in the plugin.

Comment: Of course I tried without MouseLock. And I do get the MOUSEDOWN event when I click in the plug-in's area, but as soon as the cursor is moved outside the plug-in's area, it stopped sending me the MOUSEMOVE and even the MOUSEUP events. This is exactly what I tried to fix when I started experimenting with the MouseLock, but as I said above, I don't think that MouseLock is the appropriate solution.

Comment: According to what you said, you do receive these events even when you move the mouse outside the plug-in's area, right? Is there anything you could point to me, or something I should check that you know of?

Comment: I looked at the "examples/api/input_event" example in the SDK. At first I thought it may be that you weren't returning "true" from your HandleInputEvent function, but that doesn't seem to make a difference. In fact, I couldn't figure out how to modify the example to get the behavior you describe. Can you add some source code?

Comment: This example compiles using newlib. In our case, we are still in the development and porting phase to NaCl technology, and we have pretty large amount of code. So we compile with PPAPI in order to be able to debug from within Visual Studio. Can this be the reason for the behavior we observe (using PPAPI instead of NaCl32/64/ARM) ?

Comment: I don't think so, I just tried building the input_event example using TOOLCHAIN=win (which is the same as PPAPI in the VS-AddIn) and I was able to get mouse events outside of the plugin there too. Just out of curiousity, which version of the SDK and Chrome are you using? I'm using pepper_32 and Chrome 32.0.1700.4, both very new.

Comment: I am using pepper_29 and Chrome 30. But since I also properly get the mouse move/up events outside the plug-in's area in the input_event example with this sdk/Chrome, I conclude that the problem we observe in our PPAPI plug-in (missing these events) is probably not related to the versions of the nacl_sdk nor Chrome.